# CakePHP: Undefined variable using find and containable

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Running into another issue that I just seem cant to find any information what could be causing.

I am declaring variable $makes and inside the view its not finding it.

here is my current code:

```
function makemodel($id = null) {
    $this->Make->id = $id;

    $makes = $this->Make->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
        'contain' => array('Makemodel' => array('Road'))
        )
    );
}
```

}
?>

I have also tried this: $this->set->('makes',$this->Make->find(script here));

Any advice would be appreciated thanks!

Are there any reference material other than cakePHP's book?

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Make] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [url_make] => subaru
                    [MakeName] => Subaru
                    [MakeOrigin] => Japan
                    [Summary] =>

```
            )

        [Makemodel] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [ModelName] => Impreza WRX
                        [make_id] => 1
                        [Road] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 3
                                        [makemodel_id] => 1
                                        [RoadTypeID] => 1
                                        [name] => Dirt
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 4
                                        [makemodel_id] => 1
                                        [RoadTypeID] => 2
                                        [name] => Snow
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the find call is working correctly, you have to pass the data from your controller to your view using the `set()` method.

```
    function makemodel($id = null) {
    $this->Make->id = $id;

    $makes = $this->Make->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
        'contain' => array('Makemodel' => array('Road'))
        )
    );
    $this->set(compact('makes'));
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks starting to get a understanding of it.
Can you please give me a guidance why this doesnt work.
<?php echo $makes['Make']['MakeName']?>
I was able to do a debug($makes) and the arrays appeared correct.

Comment: This might require a new question but is `MakeName` a model or a field?

Comment: I would need to take a look at the array, chuck it in a pastebin or something

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted the array inside the question.

Comment: If it is not in a loop you will have to access to $makes['Makemodel'][0]['ModelName']

Answer (score 0):

Is `find` returning correct results?

```
function makemodel($id = null) {
    $makes = $this->Make->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
        'contain' => array('Makemodel' => array('Road'))
        )
    );
    $this->set('makes', $makes);
}
```